# retag-request: [videostreaming] -> [video-streaming]

Tags: support, status-completed, retag-request

Retag videostreaming to video-streaming.  Same as https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18601/retag-streaming-to-streaming, but for Superuser.

Only 8 questions so far https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/videostreaming, possibly a ninth [Is there a free video camera software to switch between multiple cameras?](https://superuser.com/questions/46801/is-there-a-free-video-camera-software-to-switch-between-multiple-cameras).

Answer (score 5):

For very small retag requests like this (8 or 9 as you say), then it is easy enough for users who have enough rep to retag to go and do it themselves without having to raise a request for it. That is one of the beauties of community moderation and the ability to edit things yourself.

**Edit** I went ahead and did the rename anyway.

Comment: I find 8 bumps in the middle of the day a little noisy, so I prefer an admin to do it.  I'll manually retag in the future though.

Comment: Plus, I thought I'd lob a softball out here to give you a chance to stay ahead of Jeff.